# SQL WHERE condition when one does not return true, then try other

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have to query a table based on two fields such that if first field matches then don't check the second but if first field does not match then check if second field matches for a value

something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE cart_id=389 OR (cart_id IS NULL AND user_id=26)
```

But if first condition succeeds, it must not check for second condition

**Example:**

Suppose the following is my table

```
id | cart_id | user_id
1  | 389     | 26
2  | null    | 26
3  | 878     | 26
```

- on querying for cart_id = 389 and user_id = 26, I should get back only record 1 and NOT 2
- on querying for cart_id = 1 and user_id = 26, I should get back only records 2 and NOT 1 and 3

Comment: Why do you care what the DBMS is checking, as long as the right result is returned? The optimiser will ensure that the query is processed in the most efficient way possible

Comment: So what's wrong with your query?

Comment: Why must it not?  Are you worried the 2nd condition might have side effects or throw errors or something?  If so, you should spell out what the concern is.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: Read [Logical Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-logical.html) and [4.2.14. Expression Evaluation Rules](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-EXPRESS-EVAL). If that does not provide the information you need then revise your question to address what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The query that I have wrote checks for both. My need is, if first succeeds then ignore second condition. Currently it is getting records that are matching first condition as well as second condition

Comment: If it matches the first condition how do you know whether or not it is ignoring the second condition? Do you mean records that match the first condition shouldn’t also match the second condition - which is not the same as ignoring it? Perhaps you could update your question with some sample data to explain this?

Comment: you want an OR, and you have an OR

Comment: @Dani: I think vinit wants a "exclusive OR" (either the first, or the other but never both)

Comment: added example to understand what i am looking for

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I forgot that in SQL is not an exclusive OR... xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of, is to do this in two steps and check the result of the first step in the second:

```
with the_cart as (
   SELECT * 
   FROM the_table
   WHERE cart_id=389 
)
select *
from the_cart
union all
select *
from the_table
where cart_id IS NULL 
  AND user_id=26
  and not exists (select * from the_cart);
```

If the first query (using `cart_id=389`)  returns something the second query from the union will not be run (or more precisely return no rows) due to the `not exists()` condition.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=09e693f2de9d9fba322a45822178e5d1)

Comment: This is also not working. It is fetching all matching records. While I want either 1st or 2nd and not both

Comment: This will most definitely **not** return rows from both. See [this example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=8e7d0952aee6cb2dcd1707e8c81e71c5)

Comment: This is working. Can thos be done without WITH?

Comment: @VinitKhandelwal: if you want to get rid of the WITH, you need to repeat that query in the `not exists()` part (and thus need to provide the `cart_id` value twice in the query.

Comment: My senior shared another simple solution
SELECT * 
FROM table
    WHERE (cart_id=389 OR cart_id IS NULL) AND user_id=26
 ORDER BY cart_id
 LIMIT 1

Answer (score 0):

Based on your updated example data, your where clause would be:

```
WHERE cart_id = 389 and user_id = 26
```

but given how trivial that is, it’s difficult to believe that’s really what you’ve been asking all along.

===
Updated based on latest example…

```
WHERE (cart_id = 389 and user_id = 26)
OR (cart_id is null and user_id = 26)
```

Comment: This won't work when cart_id is null

Comment: How is that covered by the example you gave? You need to provide examples of all the possible scenarios and whether they should be selected or not. Providing one scenario and then saying that the answer to that scenario doesn’t cover other scenarios you haven’t mentioned doesn't really help anyone

Comment: updated.. had added that example from discussion, so had missed some parts